# regex .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a domain newspaper.com and newspapereds.com to news.com.  The rewrite I am using is

RewriteRule [paper] http://www.news.com.  The problem is it does not redirect.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule` will only try to match the pattern agains the URL path but not the host part. You need to use `RewriteCond` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} paper
RewriteRule ^ http://www.news.com
```

Besides that, `[paper]` is a character class and matches only one occurrence of the containing characters `p`, `a`, `e`, and `r`.

Comment: Can I write it as RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (paper|news)?

Comment: @Jean: Yes, that would match host names containing either “paper” or “news”.

Comment: @Jean: `(paper|news)` *does* match either “paper” or “news”.